# convert each row of dataframe to a map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with columns A & B of type String. Let's assume the below dataframe

```
+--------+
|A  | B  |
|1a | 1b |
|2a | 2b |
```

I want to add a third column that creates a map of A & B column

```
+-------------------------+
|A  | B  |  C             |
|1a | 1b | {A->1a, B->1b} |
|2a | 2b | {A->2a, B->2b} |
```

I'm attempting to do it the following way. I have udf which takes in a dataframe and returns a map

```
val test = udf((dataFrame: DataFrame) => {
val result = new mutable.HashMap[String, String]
dataFrame.columns.foreach(col => {
  result.put(col, dataFrame(col).asInstanceOf[String])
})
result
})
```

I'm calling this udf in following way which is throwing a RunTimeException as I'm trying to pass a DataSet as a literal

```
df.withColumn("C", Helper.test(lit(df.select(df.columns.head, df.columns.tail: _*)))
```

I don't want to pass df('a') df('b') to my helper udf as I want them to be generic list of columns that I could select. 
any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**map way**

You can just use `map` *inbuilt function* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val columns = df.columns
df.withColumn("C", map(columns.flatMap(x => Array(lit(x), col(x))): _*)).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+---+---------------------+
|A  |B  |C                    |
+---+---+---------------------+
|1a |1b |Map(A -> 1a, B -> 1b)|
|2a |2b |Map(A -> 2a, B -> 2b)|
+---+---+---------------------+
```

**Udf way**

Or you can use define your `udf` as

```
//collecting column names to be used in the udf
val columns = df.columns
//definining udf function
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def createMapUdf = udf((names: Seq[String], values: Seq[String])=> names.zip(values).toMap)
 //calling udf function 
df.withColumn("C", createMapUdf(array(columns.map(x => lit(x)): _*), array(col("A"), col("B")))).show(false)
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: what does array(col("A"), col("B")) do? I thought its array of columns but I see you have Seq[String] in the UDF. how does that work? Also, I wouldn't want to hardcode A/B in this use case. I could have 10 columns that I want to create a map of. how would that work?

Comment: I got a great solution just by using map inbuilt function  please see the updated answer

Answer (score 2):

@ Ramesh Maharjan - Your answers are already great, my answer is just make your UDF answer also in dynamic way using string interpolation.

Column `D` is giving that in dynamic way.

```
df.withColumn("C", createMapUdf(array(columns.map(x => lit(x)): _*), 
array(col("A"), col("B"))))
.withColumn("D", createMapUdf(array(columns.map(x => lit(x)): _*), 
array(columns.map(x => col(s"$x") ): _* ))).show()
```

Comment: I liked your answers :) Welcome